# Exact matching a mysql query on UTF-8?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

How do I make a query hit only if it's an exact match in this particular case:

`MONÃE` should only hit on `MONÃE`, not `MONÁE`

Currently asking for * when searching for `MONÁE` spits out a row that contains `MONÃE`. My collation is `utf8_unicode_ci` - so I'm guessing that it's allowing the hit based on that. Is there a way to turn collation off for a particular query? There are some instances where I want a direct hit, and others where I want it to hit no matter the accent.

I think it's a matter of saying COLLATE utf8_bin, but this seems to throw an error when used in a WHERE IN query, eg...

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE (col1,col2) IN ($mySubQuery)
```

And this fails;

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE (col1,col2) IN ($mySubQuery) COLLATE utf8_bin
```

Here's an example of an actual query I may get (minus collation) - this query works fine:

```
SELECT `bookID`
FROM `books`
WHERE (Author,Title)
IN (("James Author","My Great Life"))
```

Can collation be entered somewhere? The following fails:

```
SELECT `bookID`
FROM `books`
WHERE (Author,Title)
COLLATE utf8_bin
IN (("James Author","My Great Life"))
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to attach the `COLLATE` specification to each column you are searching, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c1 COLLATE utf8_bin IN('foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. So it's not possible to do it when searching multiple columns? I've amended my original post to include an example of an actual query I might get.

Comment: @Shaun: it's possible, just follow up every individual mention of a column with a collation spec: `c1 COLLATE utf8_bin, c2 COLLATE utf8_bin`.